# Strange reflection error on inferred type

Tags: reflection, f#, system.reflection

I have some strange effects when trying to run f# code via reflection.
Given the following type

```
type Box<'a, 'b> = Box of 'a * 'b
```

and this function

```
//iToS :: Box<'a,'b> -> Box<string,'b>
let iToS (Box (i, v)) = Box ((sprintf "%A" i), v)
```

I can easily and correctly run the following code

```
let r01 = iToS (Box (1, 1))
```

However I need to run this function at the sharp edges of my system boundaries and the only way to do so is to fall back on reflection usage.
So I created this function that should take a function like the above and a record of the given type and apply it.

```
let convert<'t> (f:Quotations.Expr) (v:'a) : 't =
    let methi e =
        let rec methi' e =
            match e with
                | Call (x, mi, y) -> mi
                | Lambda (_, body) -> methi' body
                | _ -> failwith <| sprintf "not a function %A" e
        methi' e

    let apply f v =
        let m = methi f
        m.Invoke(null, [|box v|])

    apply f v :?> 't
```

If I now run this however like below.

```
let r10 = (convert<Box<string, int>> <@ iToS @>) (Box (1, 1))
```

I get the following error

```
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'Box`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' cannot be converted to type 'Box`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.
at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue (System.Object value, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) [0x0007d] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) [0x0007f] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00014] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
at convert[t] (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr f, Box`2[a,b] v) [0x00006] in <5831a15618eafa12a745038356a13158>:0
at test convert () [0x000e6] in <5831a15618eafa12a745038356a13158>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
```

Who is trying to convert something into a `Box<obj, obj>` and why?
Any help is appreciated

PS: Some clarifications ;-)
a) this is explicitly a question about using reflection within the context of F#
b) yeah, I know my real problem could be solved without reflection and I have done so already. It increases my code size by 40% easily.
c) yeah, I know reflection is dog slow. I am willing to trade speed (i dont need) for cleaner code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A signature of the function `convert` contains the explicit generic parameter `'t`, but not `'a`. It breaks type inference for the argument `v`.

Should be:

```
let convert<'t, 'a> (f:Quotations.Expr) (v:'a) : 't
```

But explicit parameters are difficult to use. I'd rather store a type information about conversion in the expression:

```
let convert (f:Quotations.Expr<'a -> 't>) (v:'a) : 't
```

Examples (http://ideone.com/peLJAR):

```
let r10 = (convert <@ iToS @>) (Box (1, 1))
> val r10 : Box<string,int> = Box ("1",1)

let r20 = (convert <@ iToS @>) (Box (1.0, 1.0))
> val r20 : Box<string,float> = Box ("1.0",1.0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - alas it doesnt work :-(  
`let convert (f:Quotations.Expr<'t -> 'a>) (v:'a) : 't` wont even compile whereas `let convert<'t, 'a> (f:Quotations.Expr) (v:'a) : 't` gets the same error as before. Additionally the biggest issue is that I cant a put the types as generic parameters as I dont have then (at least not at this part of the programm)

Comment: I think that types are in a wrong order in the answer. Could you try `let convert (f : Quotations.Expr<'a -> 't>) (v: 'a) : 't =` ?

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix this typo.

Comment: Works with the fix now

Answer (score 3):

> Who is trying to convert something into a Box and why?

Since you're using Reflection, your `MethodInfo` is reading the generic parameters as `obj` here

```
Call (x, mi, y) -> mi
```

Then you could do an `upcast` like below

```
let r10 = (convert<Box<string, obj>> <@ iToS @>) (Box((upcast 1 : obj), (upcast 1 : obj)))
```